# Book about a boy with a father named Daed (short for Daedalus) who sends him into some virtual reality to play a game

Tags: story-identification

Read this book about a few years back about a boy who lives in a corporation where his supposed dad (named "Daed" short for "Daedalus") worked. If memory serves me right the father sent him on a quest and it was revealed that he wasn't the boy's actual father, the boy just mistook him for his father because of his nickname "Daed". Also pretty sure there was a commanding woman from the corporation who was somehow involved with Daed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be the book **Gamerunner**? I haven't read the book, but it's easy to see that a lot of the details line up with your description.

Boy plays a game in virtual reality and lives in a corporation:

> Rick is a Gamerunner. His job is to test there are no glitches or bugs in The Maze - the computer game that is much more than just a computer game. In The Maze you physically become your avatar. You fight, run and loot, all the time avoiding the deadly slicing traps - whirling blades that appear from nowhere. Rick has known nothing outside The Maze and his life at the headquarters of Crater, the company that created The Maze.
>    —[Synopsis](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0vdr0vDexkC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Supposed father named Daed:

> Daed was a mystery, even — no, especially — to Rick. Even if Daed was
>   his father, he didn’t know who his mother was. Or if he’d had one. When he was small — smaller, anyway — he’d tried to pretend Perdita was his mother, but it didn’t really work.
>    —[Page 15](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0vdr0vDexkC&pg=PA15)

I can't find anywhere that says Daed's full name is Daedalus, but the word "Daedalus" appears [several times](https://books.google.com/books?id=n0vdr0vDexkC&q=daedalus#v=snippet&q=daedalus&f=false) in the book, and I think it's implied.

Daed sends him on a quest:

> ‘Better,’ Daed said, in the dark. ‘Now listen. I want you to
>   go into the Maze —’
>   —Page 16